# Modelling and finding the relationship in nonlinear dataset

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation

I have two datasets:
1. First one is daily data about phone calls to customers.
2. Second one is daily data about customer logins on our website.

So I would like to see how do phone calls to customers affect number of times they login on our website and view products. Realistically once a call is made the customer will often not login straight away, but there could be a lag.

How should I approach this to try and find out the relationship between the two variables? Regression and such linear tools do not seem to work in this case, considering a lag exists. Would perhaps machine learning be any useful here?

Comment: I personally would start with visual inspection of data scatterplots, looking for patterns - such as any obvious change in call or login volume by day of the week. Weekends and holidays might require a different model than normal business days. If you have enough data, it is possible that you might find obvious seasonal variation by month of the year.